# How to swap characters around inside a column in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

Specifically, I know ahead of time I only need to swap position 1 and 2 with 4 and 5.

2 Examples:

```
HEART
```

New output:

```
RTAHE

12734
```

New output:

```
34712
```

Comment: What did you try? Are you looking for VBA code or Excel formula? Are your inputs always 5 chars long?

Answer (score 5):

There is probably more than a handful of ways to do this.  If you're interested in a formula, here is one way to go about it:

```
=RIGHT(A3,2)&MID(A3,3,LEN(A3)-4)&LEFT(A3,2)
```

Seems to be working on some test data I threw together.

A bit more robust, as suggested by @Rafalon:

```
=MID(A3,4,2)&MID(A3,3,1)&LEFT(A3,2)&MID(A3,6,LEN(A3))
```

Produces following results:

| Input | 1 | 12 | 123 | 1234 | 12345 | 123456 | 1234567 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Output | 1 | 12 | 312 | 4312 | 45312 | 453126 | 4531267 |

Comment: Fun fact is you used `RIGHT(A3,2)` which assumes `A3` is 5 chars long (as OP talked about positions 4&5), and yet you use `LEN(A3)` which assumes you don't really know its length

Comment: ah, good catch!  Let me clean it up.  I added in the Mid part as an afterthought and blindly assumed it was 5 characters long.

Comment: `=MID(A3,4,2)&MID(A3,3,1)&LEFT(A3,2)&MID(A3,6,LEN(A3))` should do it for any length (at least >= 5, not sure for less but that'd be odd requirement)

Comment: Yeah, I was getting jammed up trying to build in error checking when less than 5 characters.  Was turning in to a bulky "if" formula.

Comment: Haha, yeah, but why would you even bother with `if`s when you don't know what OP expects when length is different from 5?

Comment: good point and thanks for the assist on the formula!